# trying to hide dropdown in backbone error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, function, backbone.js

notification_dropdown_view.js:

```
initialize: function(){
$(document.body).click($.proxy(this.hideDropdown, this));

this.notifications = [];
this.perPage = 5;
this.hasMoreNotifs = true;
this.badge = this.$el;
this.dropdown = $("#notification-dropdown");
this.dropdownNotifications = this.dropdown.find(".notifications");
this.ajaxLoader = this.dropdown.find(".ajax_loader");
this.perfectScrollbarInitialized = false;
},    

hideDropdown: function(evt){
var inDropdown = $(evt.target).parents().is($(".dropdown-menu", this.dropdown));
var inHovercard = $.contains(app.hovercard.el, evt.target);
if(!inDropdown && !inHovercard && this.dropdownShowing()){
  this.dropdown.removeClass("dropdown-open");
  this.destroyScrollbar();
}
}
```

header_view.js:

```
 app.views.Header = app.views.Base.extend({

 templateName: "header",

 className: "dark-header",

  events: {
 "focusin #q": "toggleSearchActive",
 "focusout #q": "toggleSearchActive"
 },

 presenter: function() {
 return _.extend({}, this.defaultPresenter(), {
  podname: gon.appConfig.settings.podname
 });
},

  postRenderTemplate: function(){
  new app.views.Notifications({ el: "#notification-dropdown" });
  this.notificationDropdown = new app.views.NotificationDropdown({ el: "#notification-dropdown" });
new app.views.Search({ el: "#header-search-form" });
  },

  menuElement: function(){ return this.$("ul.dropdown"); },

  toggleSearchActive: function(evt){
   // jQuery produces two events for focus/blur (for bubbling)
   // don't rely on which event arrives first, by allowing for both variants
   var isActive = (_.indexOf(["focus","focusin"], evt.type) !== -1);
  $(evt.target).toggleClass("active", isActive);
  return false;
  }
 });
```

In a RoR app, when clicked on an icon simultaneously, a dropdown opens and closes  for notifications.  hideDropdown should hide the dropdown when it is opened but it doesn't and I get the error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'el' of undefined

I presume it has something to do with "this". Can anyone help?

Comment: you can get the stacktrace of the error in chrome and then let us know which line exactly is throwing the error. Better yet, put a break-point on that line and traverse above the stack to see why the element is undefined.

Comment: This will be my first debug ever. I have grasped the fundamentals after reading what you wrote and some research. I wonder how it is done in a rails app some people use debugger gem for rails. I wonder which is fit for purpose here with backbone?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging & https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging - these should help you start.

Answer (score 0):

had you assigned el to the view? like:

```
headerView = new App.Views.HeaderView
  el: '#header'
```

you can specify a selector for el to your view
http://backbonejs.org/#View-el

Comment: No, well this class is called notification_dropdown_view.js and has everything to do with the notifications rendering in the dropdown. There is another class called header_view.js Ill update so you can see.